# why does dojo swallow the response?

Tags: html, file-upload, dojo

I want to upload files. If I use plain html uploder (below) everything works fine.
The content of the file gets validated and I can display the result of the validation. So I can provide a feedback to the user  (which can be either success, or the list of validation errors.)

`<input  name="uploadedfile" id="uploadedfile" value="uploadedfile" type="file"  label="Select File" />`

However if I want to improve the layout by using dojo  somehow the response gets lost, and I can not provide any feedback. Why does dojo 'swallow' the response?

The only difference is this:

`data-dojo-type="dojox.form.Uploader" data-dojo-props="showInput:'after'"`

That improves the layout but kills the functionality. Why?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your code to:

```
<input data-dojo-type="dojox.form.Uploader" data-dojo-props="showInput: after"/>
```

I've removed the '' inside dojo-props as I believe this is where the issue is...

Comment: no, not really. Although the functionality is back, the layout (buttons) no longer resembles to Dojo-layaout. So basically without the single quotes it is like without Dojo.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the inputs `onComplete` event? More info [here](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/form/Uploader.html#id20) and [here](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/).